# How translate 'le temps de [+infinitif]'?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, temps-grammatical, locutions, syntaxe

> Jean perdit plusieurs heures à contourner un massif rocheux qu'il aurait dû franchir. L'aprés-midi était avancée déjà quand il parvint à la cabane de planches, située au bas de la coupe, à l'endroit où la route finissait. **Le temps de causer** avec le contremaître allemand qui dirigeait, sous la surveillance de l'administration forestière, les travaux d'abatage et de transport des sapins, et le jeune homme, en continuant son ascension, croisa les ouvriers du chantier qui descendaient, avant la fin du jour, pour regagner la vallée.

René Bazin, *Les Oberlé*, Ch 6 (1901)

How would you translate 'Le temps de causer' into English? I'm especially puzzled by what looks like the lack of a main verb in this part of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your primary question, (well [answered](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53660/1893) by Segorian), you asked about the main verb. The main verb is ***croiser*** in the passé simple.

> le jeune homme, en continuant son ascension, ***croisa*** les
> ouvriers du chantier qui descendaient, avant la fin du jour, pour
> regagner la vallée.

The subject is le jeune homme.

Answer (score 6):

At the start of a phrase or sentence, *le temps de* is an idiom with variable meaning. The examples below are picked from the internet (I have provided a translation of the highlighted parts):

- **Le temps de prendre mon bébé**, je suis sortie et j'avais déjà de l'eau
  sur mon terrain. (“In the moment it took to grab my baby…”)
- **Le temps de mettre mes boucles d'oreilles** et je suis prête ! (“Just give me time to put on my earrings…”)
- Le lancement du robot conversationnel dans l'Union européenne avait
  été repoussé, **le temps de discuter** avec les autorités de protection. (“…to allow time for discussions…”)

Very often, the usage is like in my second example, where the conjunction *et* introduces what happens immediately following the action or event referred to by the words *le temps de*. In your quote from Bazin, that *et* simply comes a bit later in the sentence:

- **Le temps de causer** avec le contremaître allemand qui dirigeait, sous
  la surveillance de l'administration forestière, les travaux d'abatage
  et de transport des sapins, **et** le jeune homme, en continuant son
  ascension, croisa les ouvriers du chantier qui descendaient, avant la
  fin du jour, pour regagner la vallée. (“Shortly after exchanging a few words with … the young man continued his climb and then passed the workers…”)

In other words, since it was already late in the day, the workers started descending only a short while after the exchange of words with the foreman.

Comment: Thank you Segorian, most useful